# Как убрать шумы с изображения используя Scipy и срезы массивов?

Tags: python, изображения, scipy

Из [Scipy lecture notes - Exercise: Denoise moon landing image](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy.html#fast-fourier-transforms-scipy-fftpack):

> 3. Спектр изображения состоит из высоко- и низкочастотных компонентов. Т.к. шум содержится в высокочастотной части спектра, обнулите некоторые из этих компонентов(используя срезание массивов).

[image: Фотография посадки на луну, с шумами в высоком спектре]

Как убрать шумы?

Comment: хотя бы переведите вопрос на русский язык.

Comment: есть там картинка на 56 странице

Comment: из нее надо убрать шумы

Comment: это весь перевод

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что SO - не сайт помощи отстающим студентам.

Comment: @Suvitruf, но вопрос-то интересный

Comment: @Qwertiy я, честно, сомневаюсь, что кто-то поможет с этим вопросом. Мне кажется, это довольно сложная задача)

Comment: А в чем сложность состоит? Сначала используете преобразование Фурье, потом убираете те частоты, что принадлежат к шуму, и обратным преобразованием Фурье восстанавливаете картинку.

Comment: @ Avernial так помоги если так просто...

Comment: @RRS А вы сделали для одномерного сигнала пример? И разобрались в нем? Какие шаги вам не понятны?
Если вы хотите чтобы все сделали за вас, это в другое место.

Comment: [Решение](https://github.com/scipy-lectures/scipy-lecture-notes/blob/master/intro/solutions/fft_image_denoise.py)